# Cucumber capybara stubbing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have an index action in a rails controller called images_controller.rb that fetches images from an external service. I am trying to write cucumber scenarios and am struggling with how to write/stub out my visit index page step. How could I stub out the images it fetches without it making the request?

Feature:

```
Scenario: Image Index
  Given an image exists on the image server
  When I am on the images page
  Then I should see images
```

Steps so far:

```
Given(/^an image exists on the image server$/) do
  image_server_url = IMAGE_SERVER['base_url'] + "/all_images"
  image = "image.png"
  image_path = "development_can/image.png"
  response = [{image_path => [image]}].to_json
  stub_request(:get, image_server_url).to_return(JSON.parse(response))
end

When(/^I am on the images page$/) do
  body = "[{\"image/development_app\":[\"the_pistol.jpeg\"]},{\"image/development_can\":[\"kaepernick.jpg\"]}]"
  @images = JSON.parse(body)
end

Then(/^I should see images$/) do

end
```

controller:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    response = image_server_connection.get(IMAGE_SERVER['base_url'] + "/all_images")
    @images = JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Cucumber specs are "full-stack integration tests", meaning you really don't want to stub anything out unless absolutely necessary. If you do stub those calls out, how would you know if all of a sudden the external service stopped behaving the way you expect it to?

That said, in order to stub it, you'd want to stub the method `get` on the object returned by the controller method `image_server_connection`.