# Stub AWS services to return an object value in Cucumber/Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, cucumber, capybara, ruby-1.9.3

In the Rails app I am building, we are using the results of AWS (DynamoDB) calls made by the controller to populate the view, as part of our replacing "standard" Rails SQL storage with DynamoDB storage.  The normal requests and responses run over the wire.  So this is one of those inevitable situations of [Cucumber capybara stubbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309944/cucumber-capybara-stubbing) where it is absolutely necessary to stub in Cucumber/Capybara and return a predetermined result (AWS DynamoDB table objects with data, or some simulation of such objects).

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to create the stubs.  In `features/support/webmock.rb`:

```
AWS.stub!
```

or

```
stub_request(:post, <dynamo_db_url_string>).with(body: table_name_json).to_return(status: 200, body: '', headers: {})
```

will return an empty result, which cannot be used because this section of the program directly works with the DynamoDB table and its data.  In particular, `stub_request` restricts the types of objects returned.  I would like to return AWS::DynamoDB objects, which are not compatible with the `stub_request` command as far as I know.

I also tried

```
dynamo = AWS::DynamoDB.new(stub_requests: true)
AWS::DynamoDB.stub(:new).to_return(dynamo)
```

in both the `features/support/webmock.rb` and the individual Capybara steps.  However, I get this error:

```
The use of doubles or partial doubles from rspec-mocks outside of the 
per-test lifecycle is not supported. (RSpec::Mocks::OutsideOfExampleError)
```

I prefer not to use a third party library, but would if there is no other way to accomplish this kind of stubbing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr/). I think you can solve your probelm by recording the results of a call and then re-using that in subsequent test runs.